# Jquery validation plugin not working on dynamic generated checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Hey guys i am using [Jquery validation plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) , 
I have to create a form which has dynamic generated fields like input boxes, select box and checkbox so it works perfectly on other elements of my form but not works for dynamic generated checkboxes

Check out the snapshot below 
[image]

for this my jquery validate code is

```
var educationFormValidator = $("#educationForm").validate({
rules:function(){
    var primaryEducationRules = new Object();
    $('.is_primary').each(function() {
        primaryEducationRules[this.name] = {
            require_from_group: [1, ".is_primary"],
            required:true
        };
    });
    console.log(primaryEducationRules);
    return primaryEducationRules;
},
messages:function(){
    var messages = new Object();
    $('.is_primary').each(function() {
        messages[this.name] = { required: 'Please select relevant qualification' };
    });
    console.log(messages);
    return messages;
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
},
invalidHandler: function() {
    console.log( educationFormValidator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid" );
}
});
```

javascript function which generates dynamic check boxes

```
function addEducation (educationCount) {
var educationDiv = '<div class="inputRow_'+educationCount+'"><hr><br>';
educationDiv += addInstituteNameDiv (educationCount);
educationDiv += addBatchYears (educationCount);
educationDiv += addCourseType (educationCount);
educationDiv += addDegreeTypeDiv (educationCount);
educationDiv += addAddDegreeButton (educationCount);
educationDiv += '</div>';
$('.multiple-education').append(educationDiv);
//addYearsInOption(educationCount);
if(educationCount!=1){
    $('#deleteDegreeBtn_'+(parseInt(educationCount)-1)).css("display","block");
    $('#deleteDegreeBtn_'+educationCount).css("display","block");
}

$('#addDegreeBtn_'+      (parseInt(educationCount)-1)).css("display","none");
}

function addInstituteNameDiv (educationCount) {
var instituteNameDiv = '<div class="form-group" id="instituteName'+educationCount+'">';
instituteNameDiv +=   '<label style="padding-left:0;" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Institute</label>';
instituteNameDiv +=    '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">';
instituteNameDiv +=        '<input name="From['+educationCount+'][otherInstitute]" class="form-control input-md" type="text" required id="instituteName_'+educationCount+'">';
instituteNameDiv +=        '</div>';
instituteNameDiv +=        '<!--<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2"><span name="reset_'+educationCount+'" id="reset_institute_'+educationCount+'" class="suggestion-reset greentxt mt7 pull-left">Edit</span></div>-->';
instituteNameDiv +=        '<div class="checkbox col-md-3 col-sm-2 pdl0 col-xs-12 edu-message">';
instituteNameDiv +=            '<label style="padding-left:0;" for="checkboxes-0">';
instituteNameDiv +=                '<input class="is_primary" name="From['+educationCount+'][is_primary]" id="is_primary_'+educationCount+'" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="setImportantEducation('+educationCount+')">';
instituteNameDiv +=                '<span name="primary_edu_'+educationCount+'" id="primary_edu_'+educationCount+'">This is my most relevant / important educational qualification</span>';
instituteNameDiv +=            '</label>';
instituteNameDiv +=        '</div>';
instituteNameDiv +=    '</div>';
return instituteNameDiv;
}
```

All fields are mandatory in form if it is generated but user have to select at least 1 relevant education out of many educations fields

for the help i have read [this link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) too

Comment: Do you want the user to always check the checkbox? what is the rule that you are looking for?

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes i want user to always check exactly 1 checkbox, i am looking for the rule through which we can set one of the checkbox is mandatory

Comment: The `required` rule can be applied to the checkbox with `class="required"`.  That is all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isprimary", function (value, element) {
    return $('.is_primary:checked').length == 1;
}, "Please select 1");

$.validator.addClassRules("is_primary", {
    isprimary: true
});

var educationFormValidator = $("#educationForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    },
    invalidHandler: function () {
        console.log(educationFormValidator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
        if (element.hasClass('is_primary')) {
            element.parent().append(label)
        } else {
            label.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m52ga6ex/)

Comment: yes i am looking for the similar code but only for 1 checkbox and this code is not working in my case :(

Comment: it works fine thanks a lot. one more thing i have to append the message  below the text "This is most important .... ", and how do i set this is a correct ans?

Comment: no actually you have set the solution in comments that's why am asking how to set your comment is correct solution or you have to update your solution and please tell me how do i write this text "Please select 1" below the text "This is most relevant educational qualification"

Comment: @vishal try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m52ga6ex/5/ - also answer is updated with the nwe solution

Comment: **So much unnecessary code in this answer**. Of course jQuery Validate can make a single checkbox "required" without using the `.addMethod()` or `addClassRules()` methods. Simply put the `required` class on the checkbox! See: http://jsfiddle.net/m52ga6ex/13

Comment: @Sparky it was already suggested http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m52ga6ex/2/ then http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m52ga6ex/3/ then http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m52ga6ex/4/

Comment: Use the `data-msg-required` to set the custom message.  See my answer which explains why you don't need to use all that extra code.

Comment: @Sparky if you see the above comments the requirements was changed.... like only 1 of the checkboxes should be selected...

Comment: @Sparky yes... the 3rd point can be used... also need to revalidate all other checkboxes once one checkbox is checked(this is missing)

Comment: Ok, got it.  I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: My jsFiddle simply used yours with minor changes.  [Your posted jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m52ga6ex/) does **not** re-evaluate all checkboxes once one is checked.

Comment: My revised "comment" on your answer then is that you do not need to use the `.addClassRules()` method at all.  The custom method can be applied by itself ***directly*** as a class.  `.addMethod("is_primary"...` and `<input class="is_primary"...`

Answer (score 1):

you aren't calling addInstituteNameDiv() in your script. Also, addInstituteNameDiv() should appear before the validater call.

Comment: i am calling it, actually this function is only part of whole function . let me add it for the help

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937601/594235) works, however, it contains some unnecessary code.

**Eliminate `.addClassRules()`:**

You do not need the `.addClassRules()` method for simply applying a custom rule using a class.  The `.addClassRules()` method is intended for creating a "compound" rule, which is not the case here.

If, for whatever reason, you wanted to create a custom rule, the custom rule can be applied ***directly*** as a class.  There is no need for `.addClassRules()`.

```
<input class="my_custom_rule" ...
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/m52ga6ex/12/**